# Image Fusion OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and I am looking to fuse two images(Panchromatic and Multispectral) using OpenCV with C++. Note that I have already registered the reference image and now I just need to fuse the reference and the sensed image. I could not find any functions that could help me with this. Did I miss something or is there no direct way to fuse two images?
Please suggest any simple way to proceed with the fusion process.

Comment: what's your definition of `fusing` in this case? What's your input (types) and what should be your result? Just adding additional channels? Coding to some kind of BGR color values for visualization? etc etc

Comment: Are you trying to combine the higher resolution of the panchromatic with the colours of the multi-spectral to generate an image that has the benefits of higher spatial resolution and higher colour resolution? If so, one method is to upsample the lower resolution multispectral imagery to that of the panchromatic, run a Principal Components Analysis of the multi-spectral, and replace the primary component with the high-res panchromatic - then back-transform. What I am saying is that you will need to `spell out the steps` to OpenCV.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Exactly, I am trying to combine the higher resolution of the panchromatic with the colours of the multispectral to get an image that has the benefits of higher spatial resolution and higher colour resolution. Thanks for your help. An opencv function for this purpose would have been helpful.
I was trying to convert RGB to HSI and perform the same operation, i.e. replace the I of the multispectral with the panchromatic image. Could you help me with any functions to proceed with this method?

Comment: Sadly I know relatively little about OpenCV - I just know ImageMagick and general image processing with a speciality in Remote Sensing. I hope though, that now I have mentioned Prinicpal Components and the general workflow, that an OpenCV person might see what you are trying to do and help you out... @rayryeng maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to fuse together the panchromatic and multispectral images, you would need to :

1. Convert the input images into a suitable format (YUV works for me,
   HSI might too).
2. Fuse the luminance or intensity values of the two images, leaving the color space untouched.
3. Combine the fused channel with the color information to produce the final image.

.

```
cvtColor(ref, tmp1, CV_BGR2GRAY, 0);
cvtColor(trans, tmp2, CV_BGR2GRAY, 0);

cv::Mat yuv;
cvtColor(ref, yuv, CV_BGR2YUV, 3);
vector <Mat> channels_ref;

split(yuv, channels_ref);

double alpha = 0.3;
double beta = 1 - alpha;
addWeighted(tmp1, alpha, tmp2, beta, 0.0, channels_ref[0]);

Mat merge[] = {channels_ref[0], channels_ref[1], channels_ref[2]};
cv::merge(merge, 3, output);

cvtColor(output, output, CV_YUV2BGR);   

imshow("Linear Blend", output);


waitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this question after a long time and decided to have a go at it as there was no sample imagery available before. In the meantime, I have generated some - see later.

So, let's say you have a hi-res, panchromatic image with 10m resolution something like this:

[image]

and a lo-res, multi-spectral image with 40m resolution of the same area, something like this:

[image]

Then, just using **ImageMagick** at the command-line for now (since it is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows), do what I was alluding to in the comments under your original question...

```
convert hi-res-panchromatic.tif  \
  \( lo-res-multispectral.tif -resize 400% -colorspace Lab -separate -delete 0 \) \
  -set colorspace Lab -combine result.tif
```

So, that says... *"Load up the hi-res image. Then, to one side, load the lo-res image and upsize it to 400% to account for the 40m resolution versus 10m resolution and convert it to Lab colorspace and separate the channels. Delete the Lightness (`L`) channel of the lo-res image. Now, returning to the main processing from the aside processing, we will have the hi-res image that we loaded first acting as the `L` channel along with the `ab` channels (i.e. colour information) of the lo-res image. Combine them from Lab back into RGB and save".*

[image]

I see you haven't logged on in a year, so I will delay any OpenCV code-writing until anyone else expresses an interest in the question - but I hope the technique is understandable.

**Note**

As I don't happen to have any geo-registered panchromatic and multi-spectral imagery of the same place, I cheated somewhat... I took a single image and synthesised a panchromatic version using **ImageMagick**:

```
convert orig.tif -colorspace gray hi-res-panchromatic.tif
```

and I synthesised the lo-res multi-spectral image using:

```
convert orig.tif -resize 25% lo-res-multispectral.tif
```

Also, note that I just used `Lab` mode here to do the blending, because it is simpler, but in the comments I suggested using Principal Components Analysis. I may re-visit this again and implement that too...